# Angular UI bootstrap carousel get active slide Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I'm trying to get `active slide object` from `slides array`, in angular UI bootstrap carousel:
My current solution:

```
app.controller('myContr', ['$scope', '$http', 'filterFilter',  function($scope, $http, filterFilter) {
            $scope.b = {};
            $scope.b.int = 5000;
            $scope.b.active = 0;

            var banners = [
                {
                    "delay": 5,
                    "position": "top",
                    "background": "img_url",
                },
                {
                    "delay": 5,
                    "position": "top",
                    "background": "img_url",
                }
            ];
            var b = $scope.b.banners = filterFilter(banners, {
                position: 'top'
            });
            $scope.$watch('b.active', function(active) {
                $scope.b.int = parseInt(b[active]['delay'])*1000;
            });

        }]);
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="myContr">
    <div uib-carousel interval="b.int" active="b.active">
        <div uib-slide ng-repeat="ban in b.banners track by $index" index="$index">
            <img ng-src="{{ban.background}}" class="img-responsive center-block">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

bootstrap UI allows to set `active index` of the slide, so I'm using `$watch` to determine active slide, but I saw in source code that there is already a `$watch` on that.

My question is there other solution to get active slide object without using `$watch`?

There is a `actual` parameter on `uib-slide` but couldn't find any docs on that, for what it used.

Comment: I think what you're doing is fine, the documentation doesn't show any other way to do this. In the $watch function you are performing a calculation based on the index. If that is all that needs to happen and you want to get rid of the $watch, you can do that calculation in advance and store the result in the data (`banners)`. In the template you could  bind to the interval this way: `interval="banners[b.active].interval"`.

Comment: @SunilD. I've just wanted a whole slide object, on slide change, because right now I'm filtering inside controller but if I filter in html, `$index` can be different, from array key. But yes you solution works for changing interval for each slide.